# Fisher exact test in R & SAS : different pvaule between two program

Tags: r, sas

I have the data like this(about credit rating and default)

| credit rating | Normal | Default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st grade | 220 | 0 |
| 2nd grade | 737 | 3 |
| 3rd grade | 680 | 7 |
| 4th grade | 73 | 3 |
| 5th grade | 6 | 0 |

I took Fisher exact test in R.

First, I save the data in the vector name as "chisq".

Second, took the fisher.exact test using this code.

```
fisher.test(chisq,hybrid=TRUE)
```

Then, I got the pvalue 0.02791.

But my colleague took same test in SAS and he got pvalue 0.0503.

I can't understand why the result of test different between R and SAS.

Please Help.

Comment: Fisher's Exact Test is designed for a 2x2 table. As the manual page for `fisher.test` indicates, using `hybrid=TRUE` computes an approximation. It provides indicates the publications used for that approximation.Presumably SAS uses a different approximation that is documented in the SAS manuals.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Assuming that R and SAS are looking at the exact same input vectors